# How to close file picker dialog on mac with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have file picker in my macos application that works through AppleScript command:

```
choose file of type {"", "png", "jpeg", "jpg"} with prompt ""
```

The problem I currently have is that users can open multiple file picker dialogs at once. I am looking for a way to close all of the opened file picker dialogs before opening a new file picker dialog but I have not no progress with this.
Is there any way to close previously opened file picker dialogs?

Comment: Why are there multiple file picker dialogs?

Comment: If user taps a pick file button multiple times the command will be executed multiple times, so there will be a couple of dialogs opened

Comment: How are you implementing and keeping track of these dialogs, or is the question actually about _not_ opening multiple dialogs?

Answer (score 1):

Following script will close "Choose File" dialogs of all instances of your app opened before.

```
set processName to "Script Editor" -- edit here the name of your app

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with aProcess in (processes whose name is processName)
        set frontmost of aProcess to true
        try
            click button "Cancel" of window "Choose a File" of aProcess
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

NOTE: to test the script above with "Script Editor", you should **open 2 instances** of "Script Editor" (with single **"choose file"** code line) then **open 3rd instance** of "Script Editor" **with script above** and run all of them. First, run 2 firstly created instances.

You can open the instances of Script Editor (or, other app) with this helper script:

```
use framework "AppKit"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theApp to choose application
set appPath to POSIX path of (path to theApp)
set appURL to current application's class "NSURL"'s fileURLWithPath:appPath

set theWorkspace to current application's class "NSWorkspace"'s sharedWorkspace()
set startOptions to current application's class "NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration"'s configuration()
set startOptions's activates to true
set startOptions's createsNewApplicationInstance to true
theWorkspace's openApplicationAtURL:appURL configuration:startOptions completionHandler:(missing value)
```